# Could you add the ability to divide a bounty between multiple users?

Tags: feature-request

I find that often I will get more than one correct & useful answer and I would like to divide a bounty between them.  Have you considered this?  Could you implement this within the API?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The API is not a way to alter the behavior of the StackExchange sites, but rather to access their content.

However, if you do want to see this feature implemented, there is a [feature-request on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) to have this added.

Comment: Oh.  Oops sorry 'bout that.  Feel free to vote to close.